# Loop and add the result to a list on each iteration

Tags: python

I have created a program that outputs 1000 numbers and then prints their sum.

How can I loop this so that it does this 100 times, each time adding the sum to a new list?

```
import random

output=[] 
new_output=[]
outcome =[]


choices = [('0.1', -1), ('0.3', 0), ('0.3', 3), ('0.3', 4)]
prob = [cnt for val, cnt in choices]
for i in range (1000):  
    output.append(random.choice(prob))
    for item in new_output:
        new_output.append(float(item))

amount = len(new_output)
print(new_output)

print('The end positon is', amount)
```

Comment: Put the loop inside another loop, using a different variable (not `i`, maybe `j`)

Comment: You already know how to write loops and how to create lists and append to them. Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by `new_output` in your code. It doesn't seem like it will ever get any items added to it, since you only call `new_output.append` in a loop over the (so far nonexistant) contents of `new_output`. Could you give an example of what your desired results would look like if, say you were selecting 4 numbers 3 times, rather than 1000x100?

Comment: @brentwashburne already tried that but it just keeps looping

Comment: @blckknght it just changes them to the type float and, new output should print say -1, 0, 3 and amount should print 2 as thats the sum of the list

Comment: @noodle If you have code that's not working and you don't know why, then you should post it here. That's the main point of the site, not people providing you with code on request.

Comment: @stefan-pochmann just can't get it to work thats why i posted the question on here, if i could do it then i'd of just done it

Comment: As a side note: Is it just a coincidence that `sum(float(choice[0]) for choice in choices) == 1.0`, or are those supposed to be, say, probabilities of picking the second number?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I have tried about 5 different things, and then deleted the code as it obviously doesn't work, i'm not asking for code at my request i'm asking for help which thats what i thought was the nature of the site.

Comment: @abarnert they are probabilties

Comment: @noodle: But are they supposed to be _the probability of picking each number_, or are they irrelevant to your code and you're supposed to just pick each one with uniform probability?

Comment: They are supposed to be the probability of each number being output @abarnert

Comment: @noodle: Then you have to write the code for that; `random.choice(prob)` isn't going to do that.

Answer (score 2):

First, your code doesn't do what you state it does in the title. With few modification, it will: the new_output, output and outcome variables are kind of mixed up.

Following piece of code appends to an `output` variable:

```
for i in range (1000):  
     output.append(random.choice(prob))
```

but later, you're iterating over `new_output`, which is an empty list.

```
for item in new_output:
    new_output.append(float(item))
```

The reason for second loop is unknown in this case, so let's skip it for now. About summing of the output - `len(new_output)` will always be 0 as `len` itself returns the number of elements in an iterable, and `new_output` is an empty list. If you wanted the length of output of the loop, you would have to reference the correct variable:

```
amount = len(output)
```

But that isn't sum of the output - for that, there is a handy function called `sum` that does what you need.

```
amount = sum(new_output)
```

Fixed code could look like this:

```
import random

output = []
new_output = []
outcome = []


choices = [('0.1', -1), ('0.3', 0), ('0.3', 3), ('0.3', 4)]
prob = [cnt for val, cnt in choices]
for i in range(1000):
    new_output.append(random.choice(prob))

amount = sum(new_output)

print new_output
print('The end positon is', amount)
```

Now, the variables aren't mixed up and you are summing up the output. To do this 100 times, enclose this functionality in another loop, that will run 100 times:

```
import random

output = []
new_output = []
outcome = []


choices = [('0.1', -1), ('0.3', 0), ('0.3', 3), ('0.3', 4)]
prob = [cnt for val, cnt in choices]
for j in range(100):
    for i in range(1000):
        new_output.append(random.choice(prob))

    amount = sum(new_output)
    output.append(amount)

print output
print('The end positon is', sum(output))
```

This code also assumes that the end position is the sum of all new_outputs (sum of random numbers). Just a bonus tip: if you don't care about the value in range, use `_` - `(for _ in range(100))`. This will reduce the namespace pollution quite a bit.

There may still be an issue with probability -

```
choices = [('0.1', -1), ('0.3', 0), ('0.3', 3), ('0.3', 4)]
prob = [cnt for val, cnt in choices]
```

Constructs a list that looks like

```
[-1, 0, 3, 4]
```

and picking from it with the `random.choice` results in one of these, with the probability ignored.